# Using custom tables for old posts

Tags: php, database, mysql

I have a site with about 24,000 posts and 200 posts daily and the database will get huge soon. So I plan to transfer the old posts to custom tables to reduce the database load. There's no need to show these posts on the site. I will keep it for search engines and avoiding `sql_calc_found_rows` problems. These are the three tables I have created:

```
wp_posts -> wp_custom_posts

wp_postmeta -> wp_custom_postmeta

wp_term_relationships -> wp_custom_term_relationships
```

I have transferred old posts to these tables manually using phpMyAdmin and use a function to make WordPress use my custom post table instead of `wp_posts` if the post does not exists in it:

```
function custom_prefix_change($sql) {
    global $wpdb,$wp;
    $prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
    if(is_single()){
        //check if the post exists in the genuine posts table
        $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql,"ARRAY_A");

        if($results[0]['ID']){
            //if exists then return
            return $sql;
        }else{
            //else change the query
            $sql = str_replace("$wpdb->posts","{$wpdb->prefix}custom_posts",$sql);          
        }
    }
    //echo $sql;
    return $sql;
}
add_action('posts_request',"custom_prefix_change");
```

However, my old posts in this case show up with no meta and taxonomies values. How can I do the same with the meta and relationships tables? Any suggestions?

Comment: The problem is that the meta and term relation needs the post ID to remain the same as it was on the "old posts" table.

Comment: all posts have the same id and structure  as the original

Comment: i see will i added an answer

Answer (score 0):

a simple and Not perfect solution which will do most of the job for you is to overwrite the table names like this:

```
function custom_prefix_change($sql) {
  global $wpdb,$wp;
  $prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
  if(is_single()){
      //check if the post exists in the genuine posts table
      $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql,"ARRAY_A");

      if($results[0]['ID']){
          //if exists then return
          return $sql;
      }else{
          //else change the query
          $sql = str_replace("$wpdb->posts","{$wpdb->prefix}custom_posts",$sql);
          $wpdb->term_relationships = $wpdb->prefix . 'custom_term_relationships';
          $wpdb->postmeta = $wpdb->prefix . 'custom_postmeta';
      }
  }
  return $sql;
}
```

Now for a complete solution you will need to replace the tables in the `terms_clauses` filter hook for `get_terms` and get the meta data from the custom table yourself using the `get_post_metadata` for `get_post_meta`.